# Cannot append extra data to jquery-fileupload call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to integrate file uploading functionality to my Django app using `jQuery File Upload Plugin` which can be found [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload%20using%20jquery-fileupload). Now, I am already attaching `csrf token` with the input tag in the template like that:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="document" multiple
               style="display: none;"
               data-url="{% url 'upload' %}"
               data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
```

However, later in JS file I would like to append some extra information to this form. The proposed way is to do that by using formData as shown:

```
$("#fileupload").fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    formData: {employee_id: get_selected_employee()},
    done: function (e, data) {  
        }
    }
});
```

However, this new data **does not get appended** to formData, which is already created in the template and contains `csrf_token`.

If I try to append the csrf token and employee_id in `.fileupload` call I get `403 (CSRF token missing or incorrect)` even though the csrf token seems to be valid. I cannot append employee_id in the template as it's dynamically changing. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dynamically appended the data to `data-form-data`, so it looked something like that:

```
data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}", "employee_id": "<employee_id>"}'
```

However, I had multiple other issues with `jQuery File Upload`, thus decided to switch to [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), it took me 3 hrs to set up everything whereas I spent 3 days trying to integrate `jQuery File Upload`.